# Proving that a latin square has a set amount of edges.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, latin-square

I was reading this article that states (page 3)that the total number of edges of a latin square when converting it to a graph is 
$$ n^2 (n-1) $$

Can someone please prove why this is true?

Here's the link: http://www.cs.cornell.edu/gomes/gs-csgc.pdf

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Latin square has a graph representation, in which cells in the Latin square correspond to the nodes of the graph, and whenever two cells are in the same row or column, there is an edge between the corresponding nodes in the graph.

Let $P$ be a Latin square of order $n$. Then the graph of $P$ has $n^2$ nodes, since $P$ has $n^2$ cells.

Let's count the number of edges. If $c$ is some cell of $P$, then $c$ is in the same row as $n-1$ other cells, and in the same column as $n-1$ other cells. Thus there are $2(n-1)$ edges connected to the node corresponding to $c$. Since there is a total of $n^2$ cells, this gives $2(n-1)n^2$ edges, and as each edge has been counted twice, we end up with the required $(n-1)n^2$.

Comment: I got all the way till the end. I just didnt know how to say it mathematically that you counted every edge twice(in your last line). But great job! thanks!

Comment: @NavySeal first I count all edges from the node corresponding to the cell $c$. Maybe $d$ is another cell in the same row or column as $c$, so certainly I have counted "the edge from $c$ to $d$"). At some point, I also count the edges going out from the vertex corresponding to the cell $d$, and since $d$ is in the same row or column as $c$, I am going to count "the edge from $d$ to $c$" again.

Comment: This representation does not depend on the structure of the Latin square! Usually two cells are also joined by an edge if they have the same entry.

Comment: @ChrisGodsil indeed, but I am using the construction from the linked article: "A Latin square has a natural representation as a constraint network, in which nodes correspond to the cells of the table and edges connect nodes in the same row or column. A Latin square of order
$N$ has $N^2$ nodes and $N^2(N−1)$ edges, corresponding to $2N$ cliques, a clique per row/column, each of size $N$."